# BATCH command to ECHO a string containing quotes, parentheses and a variable to txt file

Tags: string, batch-file, echo

I want the batch file to cycle through a folder and export a string which includes the filenames/paths of the files in the folder. So far I have set up:

```
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
echo Folder=("C:\VIDS") VID=("%%~dpnxF") >> "%%F".text
)
```

The brackets and the quotes on the same line as the `echo` command all need to be echoed to the file (apart from the quotes in the `"%%F"` command as that will obviously be the name of the file to output to, not the string itself).

This formula errors with `VID was not expected at this time`.

However, this works:

```
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
echo "Folder=("C:\VIDS") VID=("%%~dpnxF")" >> "%%F".text
)
```

But the enclosing quotes are output to the file too, which I do not want.

I have tried escaping the quotes in the string of the first formula using carets (`^`), tildes (`~`) and slashes as suggested in other posts but none work.

Comment: `echo Folder=("C:\VIDS"^) VID=("%%~dpnxF"^) >> "%%F".text`

Comment: Brilliant. That works, thanks. But what if I need to output some more text after the VID=("%%~dpnxF"^) bit, e.g. echo Folder=("C:\VIDS"^) VID=("%%~dpnxF"^) some more, text(and more text) >> "%%F".text as it then errors with "some more was not expected at this time"

Comment: Then you need to escape all other closing parenthesis `)` with caret sign `^`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Escaping the parentheses with a caret helped. I assumed it was the quotes that were the problem, which is whyescaping them originally didnt help!

Comment: `>> "%%F".text` should read `>> "%%~F.text"`; note that you could also redirect the output of the entire `for` loop at once when you enclose it within `()` and put `> "%%~F.text"` in front of the opening `(` or behind the closing `)`...

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by comments, the problem is not caused by the quotation marks, but by the parentheses.

As long as the `echo` command does not appear in a parenthesised block of code, you can output literal parentheses without any problem:

```cmd
rem // This will work:
echo Folder=("C:\VIDS") VID=("%%~dpnxF")
```

As soon as the `echo` command appears within a parenthesised block, a closing `)` closes the block unintentionally. To solve that, you need to escape any closing parenthesis you want to output literally by preceding with a caret `^`:

```cmd
rem // This will fail:
(
    echo Folder=("C:\VIDS") VID=("%%~dpnxF")
)

rem // But this will work:
(
    echo Folder=("C:\VIDS"^) VID=("%%~dpnxF"^)
)

rem // This will work too
rem // (the opening parentheses do not need to be escaped, but it does not harm either):
(
    echo Folder=^("C:\VIDS"^) VID=^("%%~dpnxF"^)
)
```

---

To apply this to your code, it should look like this:

```cmd
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
    echo Folder=("C:\VIDS"^) VID=("%%~dpnxF"^) >> "%%~F.text"
)
```

Note also the changed redirection part `>> "%%~F.text"` where the quotation has been fixed.

To avoid a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be output at every line, you could remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the redirection operator `>>`; you could also state the redirection part in front of the `echo` command:

```cmd
for %%F in (*.mp4) do (
    >> "%%~F.text" echo Folder=("C:\VIDS"^) VID=("%%~dpnxF"^)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following, *(without unnecessary parentheses)*, seems to work as expected:

```bat
For %%F In (*.mp4) Do Echo=Folder=("C:\VIDS") VID=("%%~dpnxF")>>"%%F".text
```

I would however suggest you change: `"%%F".text` to `"%%F.text"`